# Inner join ambiguous column name checking superfluous?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am running a simple query:

```
select employeeId, address, salary
from salaryTable inner join addressTable
on salaryTable.employeeId=addressTable.employeeId
;
```

I get following error:

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'employeeId' in field list is ambiguous
```

In order to address this issue, I need to qualify the column `employeeId` in the select clause to indicate which table it comes from.

Now, isn't this error checking superfluous for an inner join? I mean, inner join returns the intersection where `employeeId`s match, so why do I need to qualify it in the select clause?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  This case was [reported fixed in MySQL 5.0.12](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10646).

Comment: @BillKarwin: 5.1.58. However, please see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checking is not superfluous at all.

Although the *values* may be the same in the two tables, the *types* may not be.  For instance, one could be `varchar(10)` and the other `varchar(100)`.  What should the final length be?  SQL needs to know which table to use for the template.

The situation is even worse when different base types are involved.  You can have the field stored as an integer in one table and a `varchar(255)` in the other.  Or -- horror of horrors -- as a `float`.

Comment: Do you know why doing a `select *
from salaryTable inner join addressTable
on salaryTable.employeeId=addressTable.employeeId
;` doesnt throw an error?

Comment: @EmCo . . . Yes.  When there are duplicate column names, MySQL seems to take only the first one.